# string s[s.Length-1] vs s.Last()

Tags: c#, string, linq

Q1) I wonder if calling `s.Last()` linq extension method is as efficient as doing `s[s.Length-1]`. I prefer the first option but I don't know if the implementation takes advantage of the current type.

Q2) This could be another interesting question. Does linq extension methods takes advantage of the type when they are used or they just see the object as an `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Why not benchmark them and find out?

Comment: @merlin2011 Good idea. I'll do it. But it will be nice to hear some thoughts about the second question.

Comment: After some benchmark I just confirmed what mike z shows on his answer. Calling `s.Last()` on big strings is very slow.

Comment: Can you also benchmark `s.ToCharArray().Last()`? It uses optimal `.Last()` handling, but also does memory copy for `.ToCharArray()`. Does it work faster than `s.Last()`?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov I'll do it.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov It is faster indeed. I tested it over an string of size 100,000,000 and the results were: `s.Last()` from `Linq` -> 637-841 miliseconds, doing first `ToCharArray()` -> 94-107 miliseconds. I ran each option 10 times and those were the min and max values. I compiled with VS2013 in debug mode on my i5 3230M 2.65Ghz.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it will not be as efficient as directly indexing, which is O(1). We can see in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#75722fd194dc2e0e) for `Enumerable.Last`:

```
    public static TSource Last<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
        if (list != null) {
            int count = list.Count;
            if (count > 0) return list[count - 1];
        }
        else {
            using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
                if (e.MoveNext()) {
                    TSource result;
                    do {
                        result = e.Current;
                    } while (e.MoveNext());
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
        throw Error.NoElements();
    }
```

Since `String` does not implement `IList<char>` it will go to the branch that uses the enumerator requiring all characters to be checked until the last one is found (which is O(n)).

As you can see, in some cases, LINQ methods take into account more efficient ways to access data provided by various interfaces. Other examples, include `First`, `Count`, and `ElementAt`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not as efficient, it has a special case if you call it on something that implements an `IList` but not for string. Here is the implementation from Reflector.

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public static TSource Last<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
    if (list != null)
    {
        int count = list.Count;
        if (count > 0)
        {
            return list[count - 1];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                TSource current;
                do
                {
                    current = enumerator.Current;
                }
                while (enumerator.MoveNext());
                return current;
            }
        }
    }
    throw Error.NoElements();
}
```

You can see that it enumerates through the whole sequence and then just returns the last element.

Answer (score 1):

If you're so concerned about performance of `string.Last()` then you can get the best of both worlds by implementing your own overload of `Last()`.  If your overload is a better match then `Enumerable.Last()` then yours will be used.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello".Last());
    }
}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static char Last(this string text)
    {
        if (text == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("text");
        }
        int length = text.Length;

        if (length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Argument cannot be empty.", "text");
        }
        return text[length - 1];
    }
}
```

If you want to risk it and take out the argument checks, you can do that too, but I wouldn't.

I tested to confirm `StringExtensions.Last()` is being called even though I use this technique often enough to know for sure it works.  :-)

Note: In order for your overload to be called the variable must be declared as a string so the compiler knows it's a string. If it's an `IEnumerable<char>` that happens to be a string at runtime, the more efficient method will not be called, example:

```
private static void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<char> s = "Hello";
    Console.WriteLine(s.Last());
}
```

Here `StringExtensions.Last()` is not called because the compiler doesn't know `s` is a string, it only knows it's `IEnumerable<char>` (remember member overload resolution is decided at compile time). For strings this is not much of a concern, but for other optimizations it can be.

Comment: Great idea. I'll follow it because I don't like `s[s.Length-1]` it is too verbose.